# Fire <script src="" when class appears on page

Tags: javascript

I want to fire

`<script type="text/javascript" id="hs-script-loader" async defer src="//js.hs-scripts.com/2906471.js"></script>`

When a specific class (.sub) appears on page. This class is only added to the body on the inner pages of the website.

How would I go about doing this using javascript?

Thanks for any help!

Would it be possible to ->

'if ($("body").hasClass("Sub")) {
FIRE SCRIPT
}'

Comment: What makes the sub appear?

Comment: Mutation observers?

Comment: What do you mean by "a class appears on the page" -  you mean an element with the class? Can't you just trigger loading the script whenever that element is displayed/added?

Comment: The .sub only appears on some pages within the <body> of the website

Answer (score 1):

Where is the class `.sub` set? If it is set in your code, I would add in the same scope a call to the function you want to trigger on 2906471.js; otherwise, you can use setInterval to check regularly for that class and when it is set you call the function on 2906471.js and clearInterval.

Comment: It's an answer. The user is asking for a strategy, and I discuss different strategies depending on conditions that the user does not specify in his question.

Comment: Fab. Just checking.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Answer, may helpful to you.

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName("sub")){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '//js.hs-scripts.com/2906471.js';    

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Very helpful - Thank you lllaya!